# How do i pass callbacks in angular / typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

i need a method to run before another, it could have been easier in a component because of ngOnInit but here i'm using a service and for some reason, callbacks breaks the code.

the runData method is the entry function, it runs the getSalesCounter(n) method which is supposed to return an object but i keep getting undefined. My bust guess is angular returns the empty property before it requests for it in another service. what can i do, any help will be appreciated, thank you

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DateService } from './date.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReportsService {
  server: any;
  processedData: object;

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    private dateService: DateService
  ) { }

  getSalesCounter(n) {
    // get current date from a service i previously created
    const data = this.dateService.getDate();
    const date = data.split('|')[0];
    const day = data.split('|')[1];
    const month = data.split('|')[2];
    const year = data.split('|')[3];
    const finalUdate = parseInt(`${year}${month}${date}`, 10);
    // initialize some variables
    let salesCounter = 0,
      amountCounter = 0,
      changeCounter = 0,
      changePeople = 0;
    // get list of products from a service
    this.authService.getSales().subscribe(d => {
      // assign the products to the server property
      this.server = d.data;


// loop through the array and get the date for each product
      this.server.forEach(serv => {
        const Sdate = serv.date.split('|')[0];
        const Sday = serv.date.split('|')[1];
        const Smonth = serv.date.split('|')[2];
        const Syear = serv.date.split('|')[3];
        const finalServerDate = parseInt(`${Syear}${Smonth}${Sdate}`, 10);

        // subtract the each product date from the user date
        const calcResult = finalUdate - finalServerDate;


        if (calcResult === n) {
          // if the calc result is = n ( n is a number between 7 and 0 to symbolize days of the week)
          const daySales = this.daySales(salesCounter);
          salesCounter = daySales;

          amountCounter = amountCounter + serv.price;
          if (serv.change > 0) {
            changeCounter = changeCounter + serv.change;
            const change = this.countChange(changePeople);
            changePeople = change;
          }
        }

      });
      const processedData = {
        salesCounter: salesCounter,
        amountCounter: amountCounter,
        changeCounter: changeCounter,
        changePeople: changePeople
      };
      this.processedData = processedData;
    });
    return this.processedData;
  }
  daySales(salesCounter) {
    let LsalesCounter = salesCounter;
    LsalesCounter++;
    return LsalesCounter;
  }

  countChange(changePeople) {
    let LchangeCounter = changePeople;
    LchangeCounter++;
    return LchangeCounter;
  }
  returnData(n) {
    return this.getSalesCounter(n);
  }
}
```

Comment: this.authService.getSales() is async, cant return something inmediately

Comment: Okay i figured that out at somepoint but callbacks don't work. like after getting the sales, return return this.processedData. adding the this keyword breaks the code

Comment: You need to use promise here.

Comment: adding `this` is meaningless, you cant use `this.processedData` until the callback finishes which isn't when your `getSalesCounter()` finishes

Comment: Okay so what do i do now?

Comment: i have tried adding .then but it dosent work